# Showing keyboard on SKScene and performing action on a sprite node based on key tapped

Tags: ios, spritekit

I am trying to learn SpriteKit and play with some simple sample apps.

Currently I am trying to achieve below things:

1. Show keyboard over SKScene
2. If user taps 'A', perform some action on a sprite node, if user taps 'B' perform some other action on other sprite nodes

I tried to google 'Showing keyboard over SKScene' but could not get any suitable answer :(

Any clues or suggestions?

Comment: When you say "Show keyboard over SKScene" are you referring to displaying a keyboard on the screen so that keys turn a certain colour if they are pressed or something like that? As for your second point, that's fairly easy. In SKScene's there's a method called `keyDown:` and `keyUp:`. Create keyDown as `-(void) keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {}`. You can use the argument `theEvent.keyCode` to get the numeric value of whatever key was pressed.

Comment: I meant to say the same way it appears when we tap on a text field

Answer (score 1):

I think your should implement `UIKeyInput` protocol for your relevant view, set the view's `canBecomeFirstResponder` to `true`. When you need the keyboard, just call

```
view.becomeFirstResponder
```